# 404 error while url as variable in a url

Tags: php

There is an issue with url sending from a url variable to php file. The first url showing 404 error while second one is working fine.

1. http://example.com/fix/ajax/linksave.php?li=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fma&st=14&ty=3&tl=test&ip=117.219.231.12
2. http://example.com/fix/ajax/linksave.php?li=hy&st=14&ty=3&tl=test&ip=117.219.231.12

so when variable "li" want to send a url it always showing 404 error.

Comment: can you show us your codes?

Comment: did u tried urlencoding before passing value to variable li ?

Comment: You have .htaccess running maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While sending url string use php's `urlencode()` . For more info refere http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php .

Comment: op has not provided any code or details info. But you are right.